# POST Rest API call to servicenow using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to send information to the event queue in servicenow as below. But I get at message as

> Id = 3, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}".

Any suggestions?

```
public void PostEvent()     
{            
    string jsonFilePath = @"{""records"": [{""source"": ""Test"",""event_class"": ""Test Class"",""node"": ""test"",""message_key"": ""Test Incident for Test 1"",""severity"": ""5"",""description"": ""Test Incident for Test 1 Desc"",""additional_info"":'{""name"": ""Test System"",""short_des"": ""Test Incident for Test 1 Short Desc"",""ASSIGNMENT_GROUP"": ""xyz""}'}]}";
            
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://abcdev.service-now.com/api/global/em/jsonv2");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    var jsonBody = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(jsonFilePath);
    client.PostAsync("test", new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the async version of Post without awaiting it. Make your method `async Task` and `await`/ or put `.Result` (that way you can await an async call in synchronous code) after your last line. But prefer await over Result (the error handling is different)

Answer (score -1):

You are using async version of **POST**, So you have to create function as async and you have to await for Post function.

```
public async Task PostEvent()     
{            
    string jsonFilePath = @"{""records"": [{""source"": ""Test"",""event_class"": ""Test Class"",""node"": ""test"",""message_key"": ""Test Incident for Test 1"",""severity"": ""5"",""description"": ""Test Incident for Test 1 Desc"",""additional_info"":'{""name"": ""Test System"",""short_des"": ""Test Incident for Test 1 Short Desc"",""ASSIGNMENT_GROUP"": ""xyz""}'}]}";
            
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://abcdev.service-now.com/api/global/em/jsonv2");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    var jsonBody = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(jsonFilePath);
    await client.PostAsync("test", new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```

You can also use async version of post without await keyword. but for that you have to add aviator **Result**. this will wait until request execution will get completed.

```
public void PostEvent()     
{            
    string jsonFilePath = @"{""records"": [{""source"": ""Test"",""event_class"": ""Test Class"",""node"": ""test"",""message_key"": ""Test Incident for Test 1"",""severity"": ""5"",""description"": ""Test Incident for Test 1 Desc"",""additional_info"":'{""name"": ""Test System"",""short_des"": ""Test Incident for Test 1 Short Desc"",""ASSIGNMENT_GROUP"": ""xyz""}'}]}";

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://abcdev.service-now.com/api/global/em/jsonv2");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    var jsonBody = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(jsonFilePath);
    client.PostAsync("test", new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
}
```

Comment: If  I use the async option I get a error as "Not all code path return a value"

Comment: Is your function returning any value ?

Comment: Nope it doesnt. It is just a async task method

Comment: Can you please share Screenshot ?